Typescript issue when using array
I have these types
type Asset = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    recordedBy: string
}

type User = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    dob?: Date
}

type Device = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    location: [number, number]
}

// etc...

I have a Class
type Name = 'asset' | 'user' | 'device' // etc.

type Convert<N extends Name> =
    N extends 'asset' ? Asset
    : N extends 'user' ? User
    : N extends 'device' ? Device : N

class Read<N extends Name>
{
    name: N;

    constructor(name: N)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get = async (): Promise<Convert<N>> =>
    {
        // code here
    };
}

When I use the Class above
const read = new Read('user');
const user = await read.get();

The type of the variable user is what I expect (User).
But I have a function like this
const build = <N extends Name>(names: N[]): Read<N>[] =>
{
    return names.map(name => new Read(name));
};

const [readAsset, readDevice] = build(['user', 'device']);

Types of readAsset and readDevice aren't what I expect
const readAsset: Read<"asset" | "device">
const readDevice: Read<"asset" | "device">

So when I run get in each ones.
const asset = await readAsset.get();
const device = await readDevice.get();

Types of those results are
const asset: Asset | Device
const device: Asset | Device

What should I do in order to change results to
const readAsset: Read<"asset">
const readDevice: Read<"device">

As well as
const asset: Asset
const device: Device

Without casting
I also expect we use the function build. Thank everbody.
UPDATE 1:
This playground link works exactly as I want.
But Idk why it doesn't work for my VSCode.
Screenshot
UPDATE 2:
Now it works. I have to remove my VSCode and reinstall it. I think I used the very old one.

Well with a generic type parameter <N extends Name>, N must be "asset" | "device" and the typings you get are correct. You'll want Ns extends Name[] where Ns can be the tuple type ["asset", "device"], then have build return a mapped type.

@Bergi what is ReturnType of build? I do Read<Ns[number]>[] but it doesn't work

As a I said, use a mapped tuple type

It doesn't work for me :(

@XuânMinh <const N extends Name[]>(names: N): { [K in keyof N]: Read<N[K]> }

@Thomas I did it. Then const [readAsset, readDevice] = build(['asset', 'device']) but I got const asset: Asset | User | Device after const asset = await readAsset.get();. It isn't what I expect.

Here is a playground link showing what the previous commenters have been telling you to do. It works exactly as you want, so if you're still not getting it right, you need to present us with a [mre] or else we're at an impasse. If that playground link works for you and you agree it solves the issue you're having, then someone (maybe Bergi or Thomas) can write up an answer (I'd also do it but I don't want to step on toes).

@jcalz no toes to step on here - if I had wanted to write an answer, I wouldn't have written a comment. I have a suspicion though that there's a suitable duplicate somewhere

@jcalz Yeah the link works exactly as I want. But idk why it doesn't work for my vscode. I copied your code and pasted on my vscode. But the result isn't the same as the playground link above. I got const device: Asset | User | Device.

@jcalz This is the code I copied from you, and its result

Oh it works. I have to remove my vscode and reinstall it. It may be old. Thank guys.

you need to use a  tuple
type InputTuple = ["user", "device"];
type outputTuple = [Read<"user">, Read<"device">];
const build = (names: InputTuple): outputTuple => {
  return [new Read[names[0]](), new Read[names[1]]()];
};
const [readAsset, readDevice] = build(["user", "device"]);

I think the length of names is dynamic, so you need to use a type guard when using the instance.

The input isn't specific. In other case, I do
build(["device", "asset"]);
or
build(["asset", "user"]);
So the type can't be specific as well.

I mean I cannot know what input is. I only know it is one of "device", "asset", "user",  etc. which I defined before

You can add a type field to each type to use as a type guard.
type Asset = {
type: "aset";
id: string;
name: string;
recordedBy: string;
};
type User = {
type: "user";
id: string;
name: string;
dob?: Date;
};
type AllType = Asset | User;
function isAsset(node: AllType): node is Asset {
if (node.type === "aset") {
return true;
}
return false;
}
function isUser(node: AllType): node is User {
if (node.type === "user") {
return true;
}
return false;
}
